# Install command is not working in Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install composer. I downloaded it using windows installer.
 My composer.json looks like this

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.2.*"
    }
}
```

Now when I try to run the command composer install it is giving me following error.

```
C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin>php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: connection...
Could not fetch http://nodeload.github.com/Seldaek/monolog/zip/1.2.1, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in         C:/Users/RUMMAN/AppData/Roaming/Composer/config.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username: 
Password:
```

If I put them blank it gives me following error

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://api.github.com/authorizations" file could not be downloaded: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
  failed to open stream: Invalid argument


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
```

Just to mention I already enabled open SSL in my php setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really enabled openSSL for php CLI, then it should show up when you run `php -m` in a terminal. If it does not, then run `php --ini` and edit the php.ini that shows up in the output of this command.

Comment: Thanks that works. Just for curiosity, initially I edited the file php.ini that is inside "bin" folder in C:\Wamp\php and restarted the server. Then when I realized it is using the copy of php.ini under C:\windows. I assumed php copied a version of the php.ini inside windows folder but why it did not updated when I enabled openssl, although I restarted my wamp server.

Comment: Composer does not need a web server to run. It only needs php in CLI. You can tink of it as different programs, that can have different configurations (that are not supposed to be in sync). When you install wamp, I suppose it installs apache, Mysql, the php module for apache, and the php cli executable.